# $x<\sup Y$ if and only if $\exists y\in Y: x<y$

Tags: proof-verification, order-theory, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $(X,<)$ be a nonempty partially ordered set, $Y$ be a nonempty subset of $X$, and $x\in X$. Then $x<\sup Y \iff \exists y\in Y: x<y$.

---

**My attempt:**

1. $x<\sup Y \implies \exists y\in Y: x<y$

If not, $\forall y\in Y: y\le x$. Then $\sup X\le x$. This is a contradiction. Thus $x<\sup Y \implies \exists y\in Y: x<y$.

2. $\exists y\in Y: x<y \implies x<\sup Y$

We have $y\in Y \implies y \le \sup Y$. Moreover, $x<y$. Then $x<y\le \sup Y$. Hence $x<\sup Y$.

---

Please verify if my attempt contains logical gaps or flaws! Thank your for your help!

Comment: Please avoid titles that are entirely $\rm\LaTeX$.

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe.  It is correct only if the order is linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From left to right is false in general for *partial* orders.
Consider $\mathbb{N}^2$ with the product order: $\langle k,l\rangle\preceq\langle m,n\rangle$ iff $k\le m$ and $l\le n$.
Then $\langle 2,2\rangle\prec\langle 3,3\rangle$ and $\langle3,3\rangle=\sup\{\langle1,3\rangle,\langle3,1\rangle\}$ but the conclusion does not follow.

From right to left is fine.

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good place to bring up the definition of exact upper bound (which appears in PCF quite often), which is the "right generalization" in this context.

Comment: To me it sounds a bit early for that.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to bring up PCF. Just the definition of an eub...

Comment: Even that; I've learned that it is not always a good idea to introduce extra notions at stages like this.